# python turtle canvas scrolling

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python turtle library to draw a big diagram.  Whenever it's drawn the displayed region is the center (i.e. the scrollbar's are in the middle position).  I'd like to scroll to the top-left region. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Found solution:

```
ts = getscreen().getcanvas()
ts.xview_moveto(0)
ts.yview_moveto(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also make the screen bigger and you can manually scroll it.

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.screensize(x ,y)
```

Just make the x bigger and you can scroll manually (by default the x is 400 and the y is 300)